# How to enforce data types in query parameters passed through URL ? Is there any way to make some of the parameters compulsory?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to implement a route "/userdata" such that :

The ideal responses from api should be as below:

On error, displaying the following response -

```
{error: true, status: 403, userMessage: 'some query parameter missing',
    data: <Name of the parameter that is missing>}.
```

The query parameters that are compulsory are - name :String, age:Number

On Success, displaying the following response -

```
{error: false, status: 200, userMessage: 'all query parameters entered',
    data: {name: <Name passed in query params>, age: <age passed in query params>}}.
```

I have almost finished my implementation , however I would like to enforce 
data type checking in the passed parameters . Can you please suggest if there is a way to achieve the same?

I have also tried using req.params , instead of req.query. However it's not giving me desired output.

```
// All code files
<app.js code>


const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const response = require('./user-middleware');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Creating a route named query
app.get('/userdata',(req,res) => {
    var name = req.query.name;
    var age = req.query.age;

    if(name === null || name === undefined || name.length === 0)
    {
        let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 403, 'some query parameter missing', {name:"name",age:`${age}`});
        res.send(apiResponse);
    }
    else if(age === null || age === undefined || age.length===0)
    {
        let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 403, 'some query parameter missing', {name:`${name}`,age:"age"});
        res.send(apiResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 200, 'all query parameters entered', req.query);
        res.send(apiResponse);
    }


});

app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;


<user-middleware.js code>

let generate = (error, status, userstatus, data) => {
    let response = {
        error: error,
        status: status,
        userstatus: userstatus,
        data: data
    };
    return response;
};

module.exports = {
generate: generate
};
```

Currently the responses are as below:

If only name is passed:

```
http://localhost:3000/userdata?name=ace
```

Output :

```
{"error":true,"status":403,"userstatus":"some query parameter missing","data":{"name":"ace","age":"age"}}
```

If only age is passed:

```
http://localhost:3000/userdata?age=21
```

Output :

```
{"error":true,"status":403,"userstatus":"some query parameter missing","data":{"name":"name","age":"21"}}
```

If both are passed :

Output:

```
http://localhost:3000/userdata?name=ace&age=21


{"error":false,"status":200,"userstatus":"all query parameters entered","data":{"name":"ace","age":"21"}}
```

I would like to avoid the following Output :

```
{"error":false,"status":200,"userstatus":"all query parameters entered","data":{"name":"21","age":"ace"}}
```

when the following URL is accessed :

```
http://localhost:3000/userdata?name=21&age=ace
```

This should not be considered as ideal output as the data types have been swapped.

Please let me know if there is a way to Implement the above?